# enable the flag enable-offline-auto-reload via extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hi I would like to enable the flag enable-offline-auto-reload via an extension. I can't find the api for this though. When I set it via (chrome://flags) the following json is added into the local state file:

```
"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":["enable-offline-auto-reload@1"]}
```

When I attempt to use this in my manifest, the browser tag is not available and I get the error "Unrecognized manifest key". Does anyone know the api for this? Can guide me in that direction please?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control command line flags with extensions. There is no API for that.

Comment: Hi Phistuck. Yes it does not have any. So I have worked around it by reading the local state file and adding the flag.

Comment: This is pretty bad, as it could change at any release and either break your code, or break that Chrome profile entirely. You should not mess with these internal files.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

Later I found out that the flag which I was trying to enable not replicated in chrome flags but it was replicated in chrome application.

So do this by command line,

`<Path to chrome.exe> --enable-offline-auto-reload`

this will work for you.